# Cannot create category in magento2

Tags: category, magento-2.1

I am trying magento 2 for first time and it's driving me crazy.

I have successfully installed magento 2 on my cloud shared hosting and everything looks ok except these:

1. Cannot create category: there is no form populated on `Add subcategory` or `Add root category` button click. See attached image 1. See the url in image.
2. Cannot add product, same as number 1 above.
3. It keeps saying `One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.` I have added cron job from cpanel. See attached image 2.

**Images**
1. 
[image]

2.
[image]

**Not sure what I have to do for this.**

Running php version 5.6.x.x

**Update**

As per [this error report](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2402)

I have done this but it didn't help either.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Comment: Is there any Js errors log?

Comment: No, no any js error.

Comment: I am in the same boat with you @AdarshKhatri. I am running php 7.0.15 with OPCACHE on Magento 2.1.3. I have tried restarting the PHP-FPM process as well as run all CLI commands I could find. I made sure the correct user was in place as well as correct permissions. I receive no JS errors and no HTTP errors (all return a status of 200). If I figure out issue I will report it here though. Thanks.

Comment: Please check your error logs in your var folder for any possible error message.

Comment: other grids are visible? Like catalog product grid?

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below command through command prompt:

**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

check after that if it shows the form.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't help. PS, I had done this before.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands from CLI and then check :

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento c:c && bin/magento c:f 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

and don't forget to give the right permissions to:

> var/ pub/ generated/

after these commands.